# Python coordinates logic

Tags: python, arrays, coordinates

I have coordinates (x,y) in an array, how can I just get points next to each other. I need the dot next to it every time, there are seats in a hall. I would like to have the number 2-4 above next to each other via a parameter, i.e. not 2 next to and 2 in front of it.

I managed to do it on other examples by sorting by either x or y. Here:

[image]

The coordinates, i become here: `[[(550, 670)], [(517, 636)], [(517, 619)], [(517, 601)], [(517, 584)], [(517, 566)], [(517, 549)], [(517, 532)], [(517, 515)], [(517, 497)], [(517, 480)], [(517, 462)], [(517, 445)], [(517, 428)]]`

This was easy, because it is vertical and i needed just to sort by y value to get the neightbors. I solved this with sorted: `[sorted(l, key=lambda x: x[0]) for l in arr]` and when this is sorted by y value, i can easy get neightbors verticaly.

This is easy as the dots are vertical or horizontal and not like in a curve. How can one proceed here now?
Here is the picture I got the coordinates from, and this is not vertical or horizontal:

[image]

and there are the coordiantes if this can help:  `[[(534, 647, 9), (556, 647, 16), (567, 647, 9)], [(387, 644, 12), (398, 644, 9)], [(369, 613, 12), (609, 613, 28)], [(337, 597, 12)], [(658, 591, 12)], [(684, 547, 12)], [(685, 530, 20)], [(688, 525, 9)], [(693, 483, 12)], [(653, 423, 12)], [(649, 426, 180)], [(662, 432, 240)], [(652, 420, 12)], [(605, 413, 9), (637, 413, 49)], [(631, 410, 12), (653, 410, 90)], [(441, 376, 9), (450, 376, 12)], [(456, 373, 20), (567, 373, 9)]]`

In the picture you can also see well, I don't need the coordinates of the points on the left in the picture, because they are not next to each other. The right side of the picture would come into question for me. Is there a simple way to do this that I can't think of? For example if n=2 or n=3, i need from coordinates array the positions where there are neightbors side by side, here example (green is ok, red is not ok):

[image]

Comment: can you show what has worked for you in the vertical or horizontal case ? might give the readers more insight into the question.

Comment: I can't understand the question. What exactly is the data? (First off, do you actually have an array, or do you have a built-in Python **list**? If it's an array, **what kind** - Numpy array? Standard library `array.array`? Something else?) How are the values created? What do you think the plot should look like instead? Why should it look like that? What does "next to each other" mean? What rule do you want to use in order to decide that?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel ist the list and looks like:  [[[(658, 591, 12)], [(387, 644, 12), (398, 644, 9)]], [[(369, 613, 12), (609, 613, 28)], [(337, 597, 12)]], [[(337, 597, 12)],...]]]. I will update my post.

Comment: I just updated my example.